# Eliminar un nombre de una lista en Python

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7, eliminar

La idea del código es intentar usar la funcion .remove para eliminar uno de los nombres en la lista pero no se continuar. ¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias.

Python 2.7

```
#ahora vamos a ver como funcionan las listas
amigos = ["edwin", "fabian", "samuel", "ivan", "fernando"]
print "-------MI lista de amigos-------------"
print amigos
print ""
print "el amigo mas cabron"
print amigos[1]
print "ahora pongamos a un amigo mas (punga)"
amigos.append("punga")
print amigos
print ""
amigonuevo = raw_input("Que amigo mas quieres agregar: ")
amigos.insert(0,amigonuevo)
print amigos
del amigos[3]
print""
print "eliminamos a un amigo"
print amigos
if "fabian" in amigos:
    print ("amigos de verdad", amigos)
print "vamos a ver cuantos amigos tengo"
numerodeamigos = len(amigos)
print "Yo tengo %d amigos"%(numerodeamigos)
eliminarAmigos = raw_input("Que amigo quieres eliminar: ")
```

Comment: Veo que estas aprendiendo Python y a menos que sea para darle mantenimiento a algún sistema antiguo, no recomiendo el uso de Python 2.x. El mismo ya está obsoleto y sin soporte hace años. De hecho tu código para la versión 2.x tendrá serios problemas con utf-8 (tilde, eñe y otros caracteres), cosa que ha sido mejorada en la versión 3.x.

Comment: estoy aprendiendo con esta version :( es el instituto que nos pone esta version...

Answer (score 1):

He mejorado el código para que sea compatible con Python 3. Por favor, [actualiza a la última versión de Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

**Código**:

```
amigos = ["Edwin", "Fabián", "Samuel", "Iván", "Fernando"]
print("-------MI lista de amigos-------------")
print(amigos)
print()
print("El peor amigo es", amigos[1])
print("Ahora añadamos un amigo (Punga)")
amigos.append("Punga")
print(amigos)
print()
amigoNuevo = input("¿Qué amigo más quieres agregar?: ")
amigos.insert(0, amigoNuevo)
print(amigos)
del amigos[3]
print()
print("eliminamos a un amigo")
print(amigos)
if "Fabian" in amigos:
    print ("amigos de verdad", amigos)
print("Vamos a ver cuántos amigos tengo")
cantidadAmigos = len(amigos)
print("Tengo %d amigos" % cantidadAmigos)
eliminarAmigo = input("¿Qué amigo quieres eliminar?: ")
amigos.remove(eliminarAmigo)
print(amigos)
```

**Explicación**:

Se utiliza la función `remove(element)`. [Más información](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_remove.asp).

Con `amigos.remove(eliminarAmigo)` se elimina de la lista `amigos` el elemento (en este caso es un string) que el usuario introduce.

**Resultado**:

```
-------MI lista de amigos-------------
['Edwin', 'Fabián', 'Samuel', 'Iván', 'Fernando']

El peor amigo es Fabián
Ahora añadamos un amigo (Punga)
['Edwin', 'Fabián', 'Samuel', 'Iván', 'Fernando', 'Punga']

¿Qué amigo más quieres agregar?: Angel
['Angel', 'Edwin', 'Fabián', 'Samuel', 'Iván', 'Fernando', 'Punga']

eliminamos a un amigo
['Angel', 'Edwin', 'Fabián', 'Iván', 'Fernando', 'Punga']
Vamos a ver cuántos amigos tengo
Tengo 6 amigos
¿Qué amigo quieres eliminar?: Iván
['Angel', 'Edwin', 'Fabián', 'Fernando', 'Punga']
```

Comment: fantastico estaba buscando el como, pero no daba con la respuesta correcta muchas gracias!

Comment: @carlos, Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour]. También puedes votar a favor por ella si consideras que es de buena calidad.